# display video using django FileField uri [react-native]

Tags: django, react-native

Hi I'm working on a react-native and I want to display a video, using expo-av, a `django FileField` uri, here's my code:

```
  <Video
    source={{ uri: "my/django/HE7sU4ABuNRAvwpFfW3qME.MP4" }}
    onError={(e) => {
      console.log(e);
    }}
  />
```

Now the problem is that if I try to load a video using uri for django `FileField` video the following error occurs:

```
The server is not correctly configured. - The AVPlayerItem instance has failed with the error code -11850 and domain "AVFoundationErrorDomain".
```

How can I configure django to allow video displaying in react-native?

Answer (score 1):

You're using **relative URI** which is not what expected by VideoPlayer. You need **absolute URI**  like `http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4`

Comment: No, it's only an example the uri in the question, I'm using absolute URI.